# Order by on large number in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, sorting, pyspark, sql-order-by, largenumber

I have a PySpark dataframe that has a string column that is a large number(up to 40 digits). My goal is to sort it.  I tried to cast to decimal, but it doesn't work if the number is more than 38 digits.  Here is an example dataframe to illustrate the issue.

```py
from pyspark.sql import Row

# Column price has a 40 digit number.
product_updates = [
    {'product_id': '00001', 'product_name': 'Heater', 'price': '1111111111111111111111111111111111111111', 'category': 'Electronics'}, 
    {'product_id': '00006', 'product_name': 'Chair', 'price': '50', 'category': 'Furniture'},
    {'product_id': '00007', 'product_name': 'Desk', 'price': '60', 'category': 'Furniture'}
]
df_product_updates = spark.createDataFrame(Row(**x) for x in product_updates)

# Order by price
df_product_updates.createOrReplaceTempView("sort_price")
df_sort_price = spark.sql(f"""
    select *,
           row_number() over (order by price DESC) rn
    from sort_price
""")

df_sort_price.show(truncate=False)
```

Is there a way to compare the numbers so that the largest one is ranked 1?

```
+----------+------------+----------------------------------------+-----------+---+
|product_id|product_name|price                                   |category   |rn |
+----------+------------+----------------------------------------+-----------+---+
|00007     |Desk        |60                                      |Furniture  |1  |
|00006     |Chair       |50                                      |Furniture  |2  |
|00001     |Heater      |1111111111111111111111111111111111111111|Electronics|3  |
+----------+------------+----------------------------------------+-----------+---+
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort by your price column cast to a double in descending order:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

window = Window.orderBy(F.col("price").astype("double").desc())
df_product_updates.withColumn("rn", F.row_number().over(window)).show(truncate=False)

+----------+------------+----------------------------------------+-----------+---+
|product_id|product_name|price                                   |category   |rn |
+----------+------------+----------------------------------------+-----------+---+
|00001     |Heater      |1111111111111111111111111111111111111111|Electronics|1  |
|00007     |Desk        |60                                      |Furniture  |2  |
|00006     |Chair       |50                                      |Furniture  |3  |
+----------+------------+----------------------------------------+-----------+---+
```

Note that here I just ordered by the casted column, the final dataframe still has the original schema (so your `price` column is still a `StringType`)

If you want this using SQL you can do this:

```py
df_sort_price = spark.sql(
    f"""
    select *, row_number() over (order by cast(price as double) desc) rn
    from sort_price
"""
)
```